# Generating a table with interpolate and transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to put together a reusable but custom table-type control using directives and tansclude in AngularJS and I'm running into a wall with not being able to customize the content that goes into the table's columns using {{syntax}}.

I've tried many different variations but have been unable to get it working. I'd include code but I don't think I am on the right track yet?

What I want to achieve:

data:

```
mymodel.items = [{ number: 1, name: 'John'}, {number: 2, name: 'Bob'}]
```

html:

```
<grid items="mymodel.items">
    <column title="#">#{{item.number}}</column>
    <column title="Name"><b>Hello {{item.name}}</b></column>
</grid>
```

template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column.title}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
             <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{columnValue(item, column.content)}}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

expected output:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>#1</td>
            <td>Hello John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>#2</td>
            <td>Hello Bob</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't seem to be able to figure out how to transclude the content in "grid" such that it can be interpolated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You can manually create the template:

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/C7HTRYZ4Hs1uOC9PXuza?p=preview

```
app.directive('grid', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    scope: {
      items: "="
    },
    template: function(tElm, tAttrs) {

      var td = "", th = "";

      angular.forEach(tElm.find('column'), function(column){
        th = th + "<th>" + column.title + "</th>";
        td = td + "<td>" + column.innerHTML + "</td>";
      });

      var template = '<table>' + 
                      '<thead>' + th + '</thead>' +
                      '<tbody>' +
                        '<tr ng-repeat="item in items">'+ td +'</tr>' +
                      '</tbody>' +
                    '</table>';
      return template;
    }
  };
});
```

---

#### You can also build it with more directives:

Here is a demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/a3xOSS6Un6XE9b1hQhvw?p=preview

One directive for saving a copy of transcluded columns (must run first):

```
app.directive('grid', function() {
  return {
    priority: 1200,
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(tElm, tAttrs) {
      tAttrs.columns = tElm.find('column');
      tElm.empty();
    },
    controller: function($attrs) {
      this.columns = $attrs.columns;
    }
  };
});
```

Other directive for creating an isolated scope and replacing with a template:

```
app.directive('grid', function() {
  return {
    priority: 1100,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      items: "="
    },
    templateUrl: 'grid.html'
  };
});
```

Now I came up with this template:

```
<table>
    <thead title-transclude></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items" row-transclude></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And two different directives to clone the headers and the contents. Inside these directives you have a reference to the transcluded columns via the grid controller:

```
app.directive('titleTransclude', function($compile) {
  return {
    require: '^grid',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, grid) {
      var clones = [];
      angular.forEach(grid.columns, function(col) {
        var th = document.createElement('th');
        th.innerHTML = col.title;
        clones.push(th);
      });
      elm.append(clones);
      $compile(clones)(scope);
    }
  };
});

app.directive('rowTransclude', function($compile) {
  return {
    require: '^grid',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, grid) {
      var clones = [];
      angular.forEach(grid.columns, function(col) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = col.innerHTML;
        clones.push(td);
      });
      elm.append(clones);
      $compile(clones)(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Your first solution ended up working great! I altered it slightly to use ngModel instead of passing items as I asked earlier and its perfect. Thanks for your help!